# How to read Lucene 3.2 index by Lucene 4.10?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Getting Lucene 4.10 read 3.2 version indexes
Upgraded to 4.10 still need to read 3.2 indexes. Deployed jre 7 as required. Made all changes within a existing code base which became erroneous. Still need to read 3.2 indexes before going to take on re-indexing. How to read existing 3.2 indexes by Lucene 4.10 ( what changes to make if any in a code )

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IndexUpgrader`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html), something like:

```
IndexUpgrader upgrader = new IndexUpgrader(myIndexDirectory, Version.LUCENE_4_10_0);
upgrader.upgrade();
```

or run it from the command line:

```
java -cp lucene-core.jar org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader myIndexDirectory
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think the asker has Lucene 3.x indices that he wants to read with Lucene 4.x but your answer requires him to upgrade.

Comment: @qualebs - They said they've upgraded their source code to Lucene 4.10.  If they are upgrading to a new lucene version, it seems to follow reason that upgrading to the appropriate index format would be the desired course of action.

Comment: @femtoRgon Thank you. I will try to re-index though I thought I should be able to read old index without re-indexing. Like setting Version.LUCENT to my specific version. It does not work this way as of yet . Upgraded to newer version because of bugs in 3.2 (memory leaks) .

Comment: @Putnik - Okay, if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the codec used to decode the indexes in the `IndexWriterConfig`.  [`Lucene3xCodec`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene3x/Lucene3xCodec.html) would be the codec to use here:

```java
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST, analyzer);
config.setCodec(new Lucene3xCodec());
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(new DirectoryReader.open(writer));
```

Bear in mind, this codec is strictly read-only.  Any attempt to add, delete, or update a document will result in an `UnsupportedOperationException` being thrown.  If you wish to support writing to the index, you must upgrade your index ([see my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850249/how-to-read-lucene-3-2-index-by-lucene-4-10/26852112#26852112)).